# Use quanteda to calculate term specific term and inverse term frq

Tags: r, quanteda

An example test dataset:

```
library(quanteda)

dataset1 <- data.frame( anumber = c(1,2,3), text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum", "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source."))

myDfm <- dataset1 %>%
corpus() %>%
tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
tokens_ngrams(n = 1:3) %>%
dfm()
```

How is it possible to compute tf across all documents, and multiplying this by the idf which is term-specific and have the result again as a dfm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the trick is to compute feature (term) frequency combined across all documents (which is normally computed within document), and multiply this by document frequency (which is always computed by feature, across all documents).

You can then compute a "tf-idf" score per feature for the entire collection.  You do this using two functions that work on dfm objects: `featfreq()` for term/feature frequency, and `docfreq()` for document frequency.

```r
library(quanteda)
## Package version: 2.1.1

# your tokenization and dfm code
myDfm <- dataset1 %>%
  corpus() %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 1:3) %>%
  dfm()
```

This computes the tf-idf per feature across the entire corpus, in the same was as `dfm_tfidf()` does per feature within document.  It also sorts them in descending order.

```r
result <- featfreq(myDfm) * log(ndoc(myDfm) / docfreq(myDfm), base = 10) %>%
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

These are then your top terms:

```r
head(result, 10)
##     lorem     ipsum        is    simply     dummy      text        of       the 
## 2.8627275 2.8627275 0.9542425 0.9542425 0.9542425 1.4313638 3.3398488 4.7712125 
##  printing       and 
## 0.4771213 1.9084850
```

And your bottom terms:

```r
tail(result, 10)
##                    the_cites_of                    cites_of_the 
##                       0.1760913                       0.1760913 
##                     of_the_word                     the_word_in 
##                       0.0000000                       0.0000000 
##               word_in_classical         in_classical_literature 
##                       0.0000000                       0.0000000 
## classical_literature_discovered       literature_discovered_the 
##                       0.0000000                       0.0000000 
##      discovered_the_undoubtable          the_undoubtable_source 
##                       0.0000000                       0.0000000
```

Comment: the `%>%  sort(decreasing = TRUE)` part in "result" seems to mix things up here. Shouldn't the tf-idf for the feature "lorem" be 0 (it occurs in every documents so that `log(3/3, base =10)` = 0)? `featfreq(myDfm)` (in this case a 6 for "lorem") multiplied with 0 should give a 0 then, not 2.8.